# set contenttype by name in generic relation in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, generic-relationship

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Foo

class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Foo
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

I can now post data to the viewset that looks like this:

```
{
    bar: 'content',
    content_type: 1
    object_id: 5
}
```

The only thing that's bugging me is that the frontend would have to be aware of the contenttype id's

Instead I want to be able to post the content_types name like 'User' as content_type and have the backend determine the id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could customize `WritableField` to map contenttype id to `'app_label.model'` string:

```
class ContentTypeField(serializers.WritableField):
    def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
        into[field_name] = self.from_native(data[field_name])

    def from_native(self, data):
        app_label, model = data.split('.')
        return ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model)

    # If content_type is write_only, there is no need to have field_to_native here.
    def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
        if self.write_only:
            return None
        if obj is None:
            return self.empty
        ct = getattr(obj, field_name)
        return '.'.join(ct.natural_key())


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_type = ContentTypeField()
    # ...
```

You may want to do a second mapping to limit choices of contenttype and to avoid unveiling of your app/model names:

```
CONTENT_TYPES = {
  'exposed-contenttype': 'app_label.model'
}

class ContentTypeField(...):
    def from_native(self, data):
        if data not in CONTENT_TYPES:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(...)
        app_label, model = CONTENT_TYPES[data].split('.')
        # ...
```

Answer (score 11):

The easiest and cleanest method as of DRF 3.x for read/write operations:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Foo

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Foo

    content_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=ContentType.objects.all(),
        slug_field='model',
    )
```

You can then perform CRUD operations using the model name:

```
data = {
    'bar': "content",
    'content_type': "model_name",
    'object_id': 1,
}
```

Comment: I think this is better - because the caller of endpoints might not capable to handle generic type.  By returning the ID and type (in string), the caller can further requests the content via appropriate endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

DRF has changed and now instead of from_native and field_to_native there are new methods - to_internal_value and to_representation.

it's even simpler now:

```
class ContentTypeField(serializers.Field):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.model

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return ContentType.objects.get(model=data)
```